# Close Modal Popup on ClickOutside

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have a jquery modal popup. How do I execute `popup.close()` when the user clicks outside of the popup (initialized in the jquery as `var popup`)

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
    // Find element with class popup, register an on click event
    $('#new-alert').click(function(){
        
        var popup = new $.flavr({                                
            /* Add an onBuild hook and create the button here */
            onBuild     : function( $cont ){
                
                var popup = this;                    
                var outer = $cont.find('.flavr-outer');                    
                
                /* clicking x successfully closes */
                close = $('<img src="/vendor/flavr/images/close.png" />');
                close.css({ position: 'absolute', top: '4px', right: '4px', cursor: 'pointer' });
                close.on('click', function(){ popup.close() });
                outer.css('position', 'relative').append(close);

                popup.on('clickoutside', function(){ popup.close() });
            },
            content     : 'Test x Close Button',
            buttons     : false
        });
        
        // Add a return false to prevent anchor directing the browser
        return false;
    
    });
});
```

This is what the button looks like:

[image]

#### Currently attempt

```
popup.on('clickoutside', function(){ popup.close() });
```

but the jquery doesn't load when I add that statement.

Comment: Curious to know the main reason to use flavr instead of [Simple jQuery Modal Window](http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial)?

Comment: I am not sure if `clickoutside` is a valid event.

Comment: @PraveenKumar purchased it on codecanyon because it looked like a all-in-one solution with built in css. Just missing the dismiss popup on click outside.

Comment: I got your issue, and have given the answer. It is there in the documentation itself. You need to add this when you are initializing the modal.

Comment: I am not sure why it is an all-in-one solution. `:/` There are free better ones than this.

Comment: @PraveenKumar thanks for the link. are there others you might suggest? And ill mark your answer after 10 min SO delay.

Comment: Yea buddy, there are lots. Have you seen Bootstrap's very own modal? If you need more, check out [BootBoxJS](http://bootboxjs.com/) for replacement for `alert()`, `confirm()` and `prompt()`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks. Mind explaining why other solutions are **better**? This one seems to work fine now.

Comment: why not. I can say one single hard reason. They are **FREE**! `:)` Agree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**RTFM**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM)! You have an [option](http://dierg.com/flavr/docs.html#available-options):

```
closeOverlay: true
```

Which does this:

> Whether to let the user to close the dialog by clicking the wrapping overlay. Default value is `false`.

Your code should be:

```
    var popup = new $.flavr({                                

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Adding this will successfully close on clicking wrapper //
        closeOverlay: true,                                        //
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        /* Add an onBuild hook and create the button here */
        onBuild     : function( $cont ){

            var popup = this;                    
            var outer = $cont.find('.flavr-outer');                    



            /* clicking x successfully closes */
            close = $('<img src="/vendor/flavr/images/close.png" />');
            close.css({ position: 'absolute', top: '4px', right: '4px', cursor: 'pointer' });
            close.on('click', function(){ popup.close() });
            outer.css('position', 'relative').append(close);

            popup.on('clickoutside', function(){ popup.close() });
        },
        content     : 'Test x Close Button',
        buttons     : false
    });
```

Comment: @Emma I don't think this plugin deserves to be in CC. `:P`